# Android SMS_RECEIVED broadcastreceiver not getting called

Tags: android

The onreceived function in my bradcastreceiver is not being triggered.

I tested this by sending a sms message from different phones, but the log does not seem to show any Activity.

here is the receiver class

```
package nz.co.smstopc;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class SmsListener extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //---get the SMS message passed in---
        Log.d("SmsListener", "new sms!!");
    }
}
```

And here is the minifest.xml

```
 <receiver android:name=".smstopc.SmsListener"> 
        <intent-filter>                                         
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
        </intent-filter> 
    </receiver>
```

This is the permission i have used.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
```

I have tried everything to solve this problem. 
Did i miss something to add in minifest?

Comment: Probably there could be any other application stored that is receiving sms and blocking it from going futher.

Comment: im using go sms app, could that be blocking it?

Comment: Probably It could.. I don't know how it is coded.. but it can..

Comment: BAM!!! it was the go sms app, i ran it on another phone and worked like a charm!

Comment: BTW do you know how to stop another app from blocking sms?

Answer (score 1):

I did it the same way, but my Manifest-File looks just a bit different:

```
<receiver android:name=".receiver.SmsBroadcastReceiver" >
     <intent-filter android:priority="99999999" >
          <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
     </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

your package name in receiver may conflict with the package attribute in the manifest tag 
try this

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="your package name"
...
...
...
<receiver android:name="nz.co.smstopc.SmsListener"> 
        <intent-filter>                                         
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
        </intent-filter> 
    </receiver>
```

Comment: If my package was a problem shouldn't i get a error in log? i have a another package named nz.co.view if i change that might conflict